# How can I see what files have synced and how do you restore lost files?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Having looked through everything all I need to know is how does Ubuntu One work? How can I see what files have synced and how do you replace them on the computer if lost (restore).

Answer (score 1):

You can [login](http://one.ubuntu.com/login) to Ubuntu One's website to view all of your synced [files and folders](http://one.ubuntu.com/files) between devices.

The Ubuntu One control panel provides the desktop experience, and on a new install of Ubuntu (or Windows etc) the control panel will show you the same folders that you have synced on other devices: selecting the checkboxes will download the folders locally and continue to sync them (restoring).

[image: ubuntu one control panel]